# GPS COM port is occupied in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, gps, windows-mobile-gps

I use windows mobile professional  6 SDK and VS2008.I use the microsoft code sample for GPS application(Open,read coordinates and close GPS).It works well 2 times.

And then when i use it third time to read my location doesn't work.The mobile has windows mobile 6.5 OS which has GPS Viewer application.

when i open it i get this error

**"The GPS COM port is occupied. Please end all GPS applications and a
restart GPS viewer again."**

I am sure that i exit from my application and turn the mobile off and then open it but i get the same error.

**I there any method or program to clean the port from this apps.**

Can you help me plz.

Comment: You exit the app, but do you explicitly close the COM port?

Comment: @ctacke Sorry for delay on replying :D
No i didn't but how can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

If the port doesn't free up perform a cold reset.

Also if you are using the GPS, check in Settings -> System-> External GPS -> Access ->Check the checkbox.

Before you application exits call the method gpsObject.Close()